# Allocating 8MB physically contiguous memory in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Can I allocate more than 4MB physically contiguous memory without enabling CONFIG_CMA kernel config parameter?
Currently, I am using dma_alloc_coherent call but it fails if we try to allocate a memory more than 4MB size.

Comment: Did you try enabling larger memory pages?

Comment: No. Are you suggesting modifying the kernel config parameters and then rebuild the kernel image?  If you are telling that, then I really do not want to go with that approach. Since we are shipping this driver to customers, we cannot really ask them to have a customized kernel image. I am really interested to allocate the memory with the default kernel config values in most of the Linux distros or OS.

Comment: You do not need to rebuild kernel to change the page size, but yes, it requires custom config on the host.

Comment: Can you please help out with how to do that? Do we need to edit grub config and kernel command line parameters?

Comment: You can start reading that: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-memory-transhuge and than keep digging.

Comment: I tried doing that but it did not work.